# Positioning tick marks along x-axis in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I have a plot of a cubic polynomial.  I want to have tick marks along the `x`-axis to show that the root is between `-1` and `0`. With the default positioning of tick marks, the label `-1` would interfere with the plot.  I want to place the labels `-2` and `-1` above the `x`-axis and the `1` and `2` below the `x`axis.  In particular, I would like the spacing of `-2` and `-1` above the `x`-axis to be the same as the spacing of `1` and `2` below the `x`-axis.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\usepackage{mathtools,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=3.5in, clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-2.5,xmax=2.5, domain=-2:2,
    ymin=-10,ymax=12,
    restrict y to domain=-10:12,
    xtick={-2,-1},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny, anchor=south},
    xticklabels={\makebox[0pt][r]{$\tiny-$}2, \makebox[0pt][r]{$\tiny-$}1},
    extra x ticks={1,2},
    extra x tick labels={1,2},
    extra x tick style={font=\tiny},
    ytick={\empty},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    axis line style={shorten >=-7.5pt, shorten <=-7.5pt},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]

\addplot[samples=201, domain=-2:2] {x^3 + x + 1)} node[right,pos=1,font=\footnotesize]{$y = x^{3} + x + 1$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does your earlier questions not answer this: [Moving a tick mark](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203627/moving-a-tick-mark) or [Moving a tick mark on each axis but keeping the default tick marks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210586/moving-a-tick-mark-on-each-axis-but-keeping-the-default-tick-marks)?

Comment: @Peter Grill   Oh, you remember that.  Hmmm.  Good memory.

Comment: @Peter Grill   With my code, all the tick marks are above the `x`-axis.  I want `1` and `2` below the `x`-axis in their default positions.  Are these default positions `0.6ex` below the `x`-axis?  In the second post that you referenced, you suggested `yshift=0.6ex` to move the labels above `x`-axis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying `tick label style={below}` will position the label below at the correct default distance from the x-axis:

[image]

### Notes:

- Font `\tiny` is not valid in math mode.
- Not sure what you were doing with the `\makebox` in the `xticklabel` style so have removed that.
- It appears that the default distance of the `tick labels` is different if the label is above, or below the axis. You can see this if you replace

  ```
  ticklabel style={font=\tiny, above}
  ```

  with

  ```
  ticklabel style={font=\tiny, below}
  ```

  I am not sure why these the two default settings are different.  To tweak this, I added a `yshift=0.5ex` to the `extra x tick style`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}


\usepackage{mathtools,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=3.5in, clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-2.5,xmax=2.5, domain=-2:2,
    ymin=-10,ymax=12,
    restrict y to domain=-10:12,
    xtick={-2,-1},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny, above},
    xticklabels={$-2$, $-1$},% <--- corrected
    extra x ticks={1,2},
    extra x tick labels={1,2},
    extra x tick style={tick label style={red, below, yshift=0.5ex}},% <--- added "tick label style"
    ytick={\empty},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    axis line style={shorten >=-7.5pt, shorten <=-7.5pt},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]

\addplot[samples=201, domain=-2:2] {x^3 + x + 1)} 
        node[right,pos=1,font=\footnotesize]{$y = x^{3} + x + 1$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is one aspect of your display that is not appealing.  The labels for the tick marks at `-2` and `-1` are right on the tick marks.  How do I get them "the same distance" above the tick marks as `1` and `2` are below the tick marks?

Comment: @Adelyn: The labels _are_ centered (the number includes the negative sign). You can use your `\makebox` trick to change that if you wish.

Comment: I didn't say "right of" the tick marks.  I said "right on" the tick marks.  Look at the display that you get from your code.   The labels `-2` and `-1` are much closer to the `x`-axis than the the labels `1` and `2`.  How do I get them "the same distance" from the `x`-axis?

Comment: @Adelyn: Sorry, did not read your comment carefully enough. Yes, it appears that the default distance from the `x-axis` is different if the label is `below` or `above`. Have provided a solution, so that you can adjust this.

Comment: Thanks.  I see that you put a value for the `yshift` option within the `tick label style` option.

Comment: @Adelyn: Yep, tried to highlight that in the _Notes_ section.

Comment: Thanks.  I appreciate the additional comment.  It is odd that the default distances using `above` and `below` are different.